# How can I monitor my users' actions on my network?

Tags: wifi, network-monitoring

I need to monitor users on my network. I currently use a captive portal router that gives users access and assigns them dynamic IP addresses. How can I monitor which sites my users are browsing and the amount of bandwidth they are consuming?

Comment: That all depends on what facilities your router has.  Please post make and model number.

Comment: I can understand the need for bandwidth monitoring, but actually monitoring which specific sites they are browsing is a serious invasion of privacy in my opinion.  Consider using **filtering instead of monitoring**, in conjunction with **only bandwidth monitoring**, if you suspect users of browsing inappropriate websites.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/overview.html). From the description:

> ntop is a network traffic probe that shows the network usage, similar to what the popular top Unix command does. ntop is based on libpcap and it has been written in a portable way in order to virtually run on every Unix platform and on Win32 as well.

Here's a screenshot showing some of the automatic graphs that it produces:

[image: ntop search]

Answer (score 0):

Setup a proxy server like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) and route all internet traffic through it...